# Google app engine error while running

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-gradle-plugin

Hi i am using Google app engine and it worked perfectly but when i restarted android studio it is giving error:

> Unable to delete file appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.28.jar

I searched for solutions and tried running gradlew clean task from project directory using cmd and there it gave same error.

Then i tried to stop app engine but its stop button is blocked and can't be clicked and when i tried to run 'appengineStopBackend' task from gradle it showed 'can't find property backend on project :backend'.

Please help do i need to share any code..here's the screenshot of 'stop' button that can't be clicked.
[image]

Comment: I don't use Android studio, so my best advice is to open the task manager and kill any Java processes.

Comment: No java processes running

Comment: Basically problem is i stoped app engine but its still running now when i will try to clean it using gradle it will give error as it is already running....checked it using local host so how do i stop it now?